# Bug? - PrimeFaces Tree SelectEvent With URL Parameter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, tree

I have a page which is accessed via a viewParam and containing a PrimeFaces tree component.

During the first SelectEvent occuring on the tree, a call to setId is caught before invoking the selection listener? I think the setId should only be called during first page load?

Subsequent select events appear to be normal, no setId is called.

Here's the code for reproducing this weird behaviour:

**tree-test.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view locale="fr">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js" target="head"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="container">
            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{treeTestController.id}" />
            </f:metadata>
            <h:form>
                <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Client</h3>
                <p:tree value="#{treeTestController.root}" var="node" selection="#{treeTestController.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single">
                    <p:ajax event="select" update="@this" listener="#{treeTestController.onNodeSelect}" />
                    <p:treeNode>
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**TreeTestController.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TreeTestController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TreeNode root;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;
    private Long id;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);

        node1.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1"));
        node01.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0"));
        node10.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0"));
        root.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2"));
    }

    public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
        selectedNode = event.getTreeNode();
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }

}
```

1. Access URL : tree-test.html?id=1
2. Select a node (`setId` is called instead of only calling `onNodeSelect`)

I don't know if this is a bug or is there something missing, anyone can help?

Comment: really didn't understand the problem ?!?

Comment: After page rendering, The first node selection will fire setters of the GET parameters specified in the URL instead of only firing onNodeSelect.
Subsequent node selections are normal as they don't invoke the setters of url parameters
The problem is that i think setters of url parameters should only be invoked at first page load during the ManagedBean construction.